# how to override body background color in angular app?

Tags: css, angularjs

the app has a predefined background that is persistent throughout all pages and is defined in the main css file.

i want to override that background in one of my pages.  how can I do that?  I have given the body in index an id called "body-m".

The html structure is -

```
<body ng-app="app" id="body-m">
  <div class="container-m">
    <section ng-view id="content-m"></section>
  </div>
</body>
```

My page is being loaded in the ng-view.  How can I change the background for only my page?

Thanks

Comment: This is a good question.  Angular2 and bootstrap add inline styles.  Its not obvious to see how to override those

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS's ID selector:

```
#body-m {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

If you only want to change the page being displayed through ng-router, you should have some kind of ID inside that page. For instance, if there was a div inside that particular view, assign it a special ID or class:

```
<div class="dark-background">
    <!-- your stuff goes here! -->
</div>
```

Then use the .dark-background selector in CSS.

Comment: Hello,  I tried that but what is happening is that the full page is not changing background.  I have a bootstrap container with some content in it.  Only the bootstrap container gets different background.

Comment: Have you seen my latest addition? Maybe it will be helpful. Just add an ID or a CSS class to whatever goes inside your page. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change color throughout the project then you can add this CSS in style.scss.

```css
body{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```